# How do I fix emscripten link error unresolved symbol: glBlitFramebuffer

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, sdl-2, emscripten

I'm using emscripten 1.37.40 to port an existing OpenGL application.  When I build and link I end up with a single unresolved external symbol:

`warning: unresolved symbol: glBlitFramebuffer`

I tried updating emscripten to sdk-tag-1.38.0-64bit but ended up with the same result.

My link flags are:

`"-s USE_SDL=2 -s FULL_ES3=1 -s FULL_ES2=1 -s USE_FREETYPE=1 -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 -s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 -s SAFE_HEAP=1 --bind -s WASM=1"`

If I comment out the glBlitFramebuffer line the build succeeds so all my other OpenGL calls are sucessfully translated.

Is glBlitFramebuffer supported with emscripten?  If so, how can I get it to resolve?  If not, how can I add support?

Comment: Looking in emscripten/1.37.40/system/lib/gl.c I see a declaration for glBlitFramebuffer but not an associated string match in GetProcAddress.  I added the string match and rebuilt gl.bc but I still get unresloved.  Any suggestions on where to look next?

Comment: You may need to add `-s USE_WEBGL2=1`

Comment: This fixed my link problem!  Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is not available to GL ES 2.0 contexts so you'll need to enable WebGL 2 support, by adding `-s USE_WEBGL2=1` to your linker flags.